# Displaying an Array struct c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct

The problem is that when I try to display this array, it returns me the memory direction of each component . Thanks a lot in advance and I´m sorry if that was answered but I could not find it.
EDITED

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    struct tabla{
        int Ar[9][9];
    };
    void print(){
        tabla matrix[9][9]={{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
        {9,8,7,4,5,6,1,2,3},
        {7,3,2,1,5,6,4,8,9},
        {9,5,1,7,5,3,4,8,6},
        {7,4,1,8,5,2,9,6,3},
        {3,6,9,2,5,8,7,8,4},
        {0,1,4,7,2,5,8,8,7},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                cout<<matrix[i][j].Ar<<' ';
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }   `

    int main(){

        print();
        }
```

I tried by writing (since I´ve read in many places that this is due to pointers)
cout<<**new[i][j].Ar<<' ';  which works but only for the first component of each 'vector' after that it prints zeros.

Comment: `new` is a keyword in C++.

Comment: Please show the real code, cleaned up and reduced to the minimal amount necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You need a similar loop for the array *inside* each `Array` instance as the one you're using for the array of `Array`s. They are called `some_other_name_than_new[i][j].Ar[k][l]` if you're looping over `k`and `l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you mean something as the following

```
#include <iostream>

struct Array
{
    const static size_t N = 9;
    int Ar[N][N];
};

void print()
{
    Array *a = new Array 
    {
        {
            {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
            {9,8,7,4,5,6,1,2,3},
            {7,3,2,1,5,6,4,8,9},
            {9,5,1,7,5,3,4,8,6},
            {7,4,1,8,5,2,9,6,3},
            {3,6,9,2,5,8,7,8,4},
            {0,1,4,7,2,5,8,8,7},
            {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
        }
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < Array::N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < Array::N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << ( *a ).Ar[i][j] <<' ';
        }
        std::cout<< std::endl;
    }

    delete a;
}   


int main()
{
    print();
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 4 5 6 1 2 3 
7 3 2 1 5 6 4 8 9 
9 5 1 7 5 3 4 8 6 
7 4 1 8 5 2 9 6 3 
3 6 9 2 5 8 7 8 4 
0 1 4 7 2 5 8 8 7 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Take into account that you could use smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` inside function print.

Answer (score -1):

You're using the name `new` for a variable name, which will make your code behave completely different from what you might be expecting.
Use something else. Also, `Array` already exists in `std::`, so this is a very bad choice, too.

Comment: Uh no, trying to use `new` as an identifier will result in a compiler error.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, exactly. The point here is that this thing has too many errors and can't be the one OP was compiling in the first place.